# U1 bandwidth limit not enforced

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-one

In U1 preferences, setting "limit bandwidth" option is ignored by sync service, ie. although the preferences show a limit of 30 kbps, U1 is uploading up to 350 kbps, although all files appear to be already synced.  This causes massive slowdowns among the home network, rendering it nigh unusable.

Comment: Also: using Maverick, upgraded from Lucid. If any pertinent info is needed, please ask.

Comment: Yes it isn't, I've tested it too. When Ubuntu One Client starts syncing with a very low set bandwidth limit the hole network gets collapsed instantly.

Answer (score 2):

We've seen reports about this, but it always ended up being a perceptual issue rather than an actual one. The issue is that the way to limit bandwidth is sending a bunch of stuff and then waiting a while; this averages out to the requested bandwidth cap, but people (and monitoring tools) seem to expect a sub-second granularity, which we don't yet provide. All this is tracked in [bug 600832](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/600832).

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified. I confirmed U1 as the issue: originally I called Netgear, thinking their router was the problem. Through troubleshooting, we used three networked computers to find the cause of the slowdown on the network. We pinpointed the PC in question, and after killing U1, the network again goes back to normal speeds (tested on speedtest.net). So it's not a question of perception, but an actual problem.